# ssl connection on MAMP not working

Tags: apache, ssl, mamp

I set up a server with MAMP and tried to create an ssl connection. I followed [this guide](http://themetaq.com/articles/configure-local-mamp-https-connection) 
which was very easy to follow, but when I un-comment the following line

```
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

in the Mamp/conf/apache/httpd.conf file, I get the following error when trying to start the server:

```
Apache couldn't be started. Please check your MAMP installation and configuration.
```

in the httpd-ssl file, there's the line:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/server.crt"
```

and I made sure that the "server.crt" file exists there.

I have very little knowledge in apache (that's why I'm using MAMP), so I don't know how to debug this. any suggestions what can be the problem, or how to check that?

Annoying update: even when I comment out the line again, the MAMP server is running, but now I get an SSL error on every page I try to open.